# python Socket server with real ip address

Tags: python, sockets, ip

I am playing with my python server, but I'm through with using localhost and I want to go over the internet. My code thus-far is:

```
import socket
import threading
import socketserver

class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        data = self.request.recv(1024)
        cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
        response = "{}: {}".format(cur_thread.name, data)
        self.request.sendall(b'worked') 

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

def client(ip, port, message):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((ip, port))
    try:
        sock.sendall(message)
        response = sock.recv(1024)
        print("Received: {}".format(response))
    finally:
        sock.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Port 0 means to select an arbitrary unused port
    HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 9001

    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address

    # Start a thread with the server -- that thread will then start one
    # more thread for each request
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    # Exit the server thread when the main thread terminates
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    print("Server loop running in thread:", server_thread.name)
    ip = '12.34.56.789' #Not my real ip address This is just to hide my ip
    print(ip, PORT)

    client(ip, PORT, b'Hello World 1')
    #client(ip, port, b'Hello World 2')
    #client(ip, port, b'Hello World 3')

    server.shutdown()
```

When I run this i get the error:

```
Server loop running in thread: Thread-1
12.34.56.789 9001
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/serverTesty.py", line 43, in <module>
    client(ip, PORT, b'Hello World 1')
  File "C:/Python32/serverTesty.py", line 18, in client
    sock.connect((ip, port))
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I know the port works because when I use canyouseeme.org on port 9001 when my program is running it says its active and working. So I think I just have my connection wrong somewhere.

Comment: The code you're showing us is clearly not the code you're running, because your code has a hardcoded `ip = '12.34.56.789'`, and the output of `print(ip, PORT)` is `12.45.29.122 9001`. Please show us the actual code.

Comment: Well, I was trying to hide my ip by using a fake one, but I forgot to remove the one in the output, sorry. Its 123456789 in an ip fashion, so it wasn't meant to be real

Comment: OK, you're now listening on 0.0.0.0, but your client is still connecting to your router's public IP address, not to your server. You still need one of the changes from the main part of my answer. (Unless you want this to be LAN-only, in which case you need to connect to the 192. address instead of the 12. address.)

Comment: I have done the port forwarding. The computer is directly connected to my modem so I just forwarded it from the modem to computer.

Comment: Can I also note that in the `client` class you should use the `__init__` function rather than just sticking your code in the class. Then the variables will not overlap, i.e. when you you call `sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`, for the second time you will get an error because the two variables are overwriting each other. Not an answer the question, but it simply is good practice. *"It gets me all worked up just looking at it."- Jamie Hyneman, co-host of the show "Mythbusters".*

Answer (score 27):

> ip = '12.34.56.789' #Not my real ip address, its the one i got from whatismyip.org

The first problem is that '12.34.56.789' isn't a valid IP address at all. Each component has to fit in 8 bits (0-255); 789 is impossible. But I assume that isn't the actual code you're running, because the output shows 12.45.29.122.

The second problem is that you're using an address that isn't your real address.

Your machine presumably has an internal IP address, that can only be accessed from your LAN. Then, your *router* has an external IP address. The router uses a technique called Network Address Translation to let each machine on your LAN pretend that external address belongs to them, when they're acting as clients (which is why whatismyip.org shows you that address). But that doesn't work when they're acting as servers.

If you think about it, there's really no way it could work. If you make an outbound connection, and someone replies, the router knows that the reply should go to your machine. But if someone just comes along and talks to the router out of the blue, how could it know which machine to send the connection to?

If you're trying to connect from inside the same LAN, there's a very easy solution: use the server's real internal address, not the router's external address.

If you need to connect from outside, you can't, without some extra work. There are four ways around this:

1. Give your machine a real publicly-addressable IP address (e.g., by putting it on the router's DMZ). This is generally not even an option for home users, and it's a bad option for people who don't know what they're doing (unless you want your machine to be part of someone's botnet by lunchtime).
2. Set up static port forwarding in your router's configuration. This is different for each router, but the idea is that you tell it "if someone comes looking for port 9001, always send them to machine 192.168.1.64".
3. Use UPnP to set up port forwarding dynamically.
4. Set up a NAT hole punching.

Options 3 and 4 are more complex, and I think option 2 is the one you want, so I won't explain them.

On top of all that:

```
HOST, PORT = "192.168.1.64", 9001

server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
```

You've told the server explicitly "listen on 192.168.1.64". Even if you put your server machine on the DMZ, so it had addresses 192.168.1.64 and 12.45.29.122, your program is only listening for connections on the first one, so nobody would be able to reach it using the second. If you want to listen on all addresses, use 0.0.0.0.

In the edited version, you're now listening on 0.0.0.0, and connecting to the router's public IP, and you claim to have set up port forwarding on the router, and you're still getting the exact same error.

If that's all correct, there are three obvious things that could be going wrong:

1. You're not actually port forwarding; something is wrong with the setup.
2. You're not actually listening on 0.0.0.0:9001.
3. You've got a firewall blocking the connection.

There are a few tests you can do to narrow things down.

1. Open two terminals. In one, type `nc -kl 9001`. In the other, type `nc 12.34.56.78 9001`. They should connect up, so anything you type into one window appears in the other (maybe only after you hit Return). If that works, the port forwarding is working, and there's no firewall problem, so it's a problem in your code.
2. If that didn't work, please post exactly what you saw in each window. Then Ctrl-C the second `nc`, and type `nc 192.168.1.64 9001`. If that now works, either the port forwarding isn't set up right, unless you have a clever firewall that allows same-host (or same-interface) connections but not remote connections.
3. If neither one worked, it's probably a firewall problem. (Unless you're wrong about your IP addresses or something.) You can probably find logs somewhere, but without knowing what platform you're on and what firewall you're using it's hard to offer much help. (Also, that's probably a problem for a different site than SO.)

If you're on Windows, or some linux distros, you need to get a copy of `nc` (netcat) from somewhere; on most linux distros, and Mac, it should be built in. Also, GNU, BSD, and Hobbit `nc` are slightly different, so if `nc -kl 6000` gives you an error, you might have to read the man page or `--help`. (If I remember right, Hobbit `nc` requires `-l -p6000`, BSD requires `-l 6000`, GNU allows either.)

Or you may want [ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/), a re-implementation of netcat that I know can handle the syntax I used above, and has a single-file static executable for Windows.

If you can't get started with `nc`, at least try changing your code to connect to 192.168.1.64 instead of 12.34.56.78. If that fixes the problem, at least you'll know it's either port forwarding or a firewall that allows same-host/interface connections but not remote.

Comment: I tried that and pasted the edited code above, but I still get the error.

Comment: Sorry, what is the "that" you tried? You have multiple problems; just fixing one of them isn't going to help. For example, if you fixed the server to listen on 0.0.0.0, but your client is still connecting to the router's IP address without any port forwarding, it's not going to help. Or, if you set up port forwarding, or otherwise changed the client to connect to the a real address, but left the server listening on a different address, it's not going to work.

Comment: What do you mean by terminal? I'm on windows 7.

Comment: I think in Windows 7, the Start Menu name is "Command Prompt", and the default window name is "Console", but I'm not positive; they change it every few years. You can also just Win-R and type "cmd".

Comment: cmd.exe cannot run those commands and I have no idea how to use ncat, when I click on it's exe it closes instantly.
I have used canyouseeme.org with positive results on the port I used. If I use the 192.168.1.64 to connect the client it works fine.

Comment: If I use two computers I can make it connect by using 192.168.1.64 for the client. If I switch it to 12.34.56.78 then it fails to connect.

Comment: OK, so your port forwarding isn't actually set up properly. This is a problem with your network setup, not your code, so SO isn't the place to get help.

Comment: As for "cmd.exe cannot run those commands", I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that, but it sounds like you have no idea how to use the command prompt, or how to run console tools. It's almost impossible to debug network problems, much less network software, without that basic knowledge, so I'd suggest finding a good tutorial.

Comment: How else would one use cmd prompt... You type the cmd in and press enter. I type "nc-kl 9000" I get "nc is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: "If you're on Windows, or some linux distros, you need to get a copy of nc (netcat) from somewhere"… "Or you may want ncat…" If you didn't do either of those, and you're on Windows, you don't have either nc or ncat, so of course you can't run them.