# How can i connect to my python socket server from a different device?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm new to socket programming but with the help of a tutorial i wrote a simple Server and Client. It works
if i connect to the server from the same device the server runs on but if i try to connect from another device it doesn't work. I tried to disable my firewall and some other tips on similar questions but it doesn't work.

This is the Server:

```
import threading
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

HOSTNAME = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 50000
print(HOSTNAME, PORT)
s.bind((HOSTNAME, PORT))

s.listen()

clientList = []

def func():
   while True:
       conn, addr = s.accept()
       conn.send(str.encode("Connected"))
       print(addr, " connected")
       clientList.append(conn)
       t = threading.Thread(target=func2, args=(conn, addr,)).start()

def func2(x, y):
   print(bytes.decode(x.recv(1024)))
   x.send(str.encode("Type your name"))
   y = bytes.decode(x.recv(1024))
   for z in clientList:
       z.send(str.encode(y + " connected"))
   while True:
       try:
           v = bytes.decode(x.recv(1024))
           q = str(y)
           h = q + " sent: " + v
           print(h)
           for z in clientList:
               z.send(str.encode(h))
           if v == "disconnect":
               x.send(str.encode("disconnect"))
               clientList.remove(x)
               x.close()
               threading.current_thread()._delete()
               break
           time.sleep(0.01)
       except:
           clientList.remove(x)
           for z in clientList:
               z.send(str.encode(y + " disconnected"))
           print(y + " disconnected")
           x.close()
           threading.current_thread()._delete()
           break


func()
```

This is the Client:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

HOSTNAME = "192.168.56.1" # server local ip
PORT = 8080

def Listen(i):
   while True:
       try:
           k = bytes.decode(i.recv(1024))
           if k == "disconnect":
               i.close()
               threading.current_thread()._delete()
               break
           print(k)
           time.sleep(0.01)
       except:
           print("Disconnected")
           i.close()
           threading.current_thread()._delete()
           break

def Activate(i):
   t = threading.Thread(target=Listen, args=(i,))
   t.start()

def InputHandler():
   while True:
       time.sleep(1)
       v = input("")
       if v == "connect":
           try:
               s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
               s.connect((HOSTNAME, PORT))
               s.send(str.encode("connected"))
               Activate(s)
               time.sleep(1)
           except:
               print("Failed")
       elif v == "close":
           try:
               s.send(str.encode("disconnect"))
               break
           except:
               break
       else:
           try:
               s.send(str.encode(v))
           except:
               print("Failed")
InputHandler()
```

any ideas what's wrong? please let me knwow.

Comment: Take a look at [python Socket server with real ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631791/python-socket-server-with-real-ip-address).

Comment: For the moment i just want it to work on two devices in my local network so i shouldn't need to set up port forwarding etc. should i?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, you shouldn't need port forwarding for the simple case you are describing
(that is: if both machines are on the same LAN).
But the link provided by @AvivYaniv in the comments though has some notes about what you are asking which are:

> If you're trying to connect from inside the same LAN, there's a very easy solution: use the server's real internal address, not the router's external address.

It seems like you already know what is the IP address of the server machine,
because in the client you write the `HOSTNAME` variable as equal to `192.168.56.1`.

Anyway though try setting your server's bind address to empty. ie instead of:

```
HOSTNAME = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

try:

```
HOSTNAME = ''
```

at the server side.

Also there are some useful notes on [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#creating-a-socket) tutorial like:

> A couple things to notice: we used `socket.gethostname()` so that the socket would be visible to the outside world. If we had used `s.bind(('localhost', 80))` or `s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 80))` we would still have a "server" socket, but one that was only visible within the same machine. `s.bind(('', 80))` specifies that the socket is reachable by any address the machine happens to have.

### Edit 1:

If you are not using VMs, then no problem: just find the IP of the server machine and put into the `HOSTNAME` of the client. If you set the server's `HOSTNAME` to empty then the client should connect to the IP of the server. Try finding your IP (NOT the router's external IP but your server's machine LAN IP). For example if your are on Windows, go to Control Panel like shown in [this](https://www.tp-link.com/gr/support/faq/838/#windows%2010) tutorial.

Comment: if i set HOSTNAME to "" what should i write for the client because it doesn't work. And i'm not using a VM. I got one installed but its not active. Should i try to delete it? I also tryed socket.gethostname() and it also didn't work.

Comment: edit: HOSTNAME = "" works. i had the wrong port for client but still doesn't work from another device.

Comment: No, you don't need to delete VirtualBox or any VM, since you are not using those. That should not be needed at all then. Don't mess with VirtualBox if you are not using it. See my **Edit 1** entitled text in my edited answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I think it actually was the VM because when i deleted it it showed me 192.168.178.94 as my ip and if i use that one it works so thank you.

Comment: I was not implying to delete any VM or VirtualBox! You could probably use a more powerful tool like `ipconfig` in Windows command prompt where you could definetly find all your server's IPs there. This doesn't have to do with VirtualBox. Sorry for your VM loss. :( We could do this without messing with VirtualBox.

Comment: didn't need or use the VM anyways.