# Python server get socket messages without same network

Tags: python, sockets, server, network-programming, wifi

I want to send socket message from my phone to python server, but it works only when I connected to the same network (WiFi). It is possible to get the messages with python if they sent with another network?

I have been looking for an answer for a long time I have not found. No question answers that

My python server that get messages only at the same network with the client:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket()
server.bind(("10.0.0.2", 12345))

server.listen()

(client, (ipNum, portNum)) = server.accept()
print("Client connected")


while True:
    message = input(">>>")

    client.send(message.encode())

    print(client.recv(21).decode())
```

Comment: I assume you replaced LAN IP address of your server with "140.70.04.64". is this correct? By doing so you mislead people and make hard life for them to help you :-) Please update your post to reflect reality - no one will be able to connect your LAN server [on private network address range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) anyway

Comment: Ok... got it thank's

Answer (score 0):

i assume that 10.0.0.2 is your private ip(internal ip) , try replacing that to your public router ip, you can get that https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip&rlz=1C1SQJL_enIN847IN847&oq=what+is+my+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j0l2j0i433j0l3.2925j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 .

if that didnt work then you can simple forward this ip and port number using ngrok or some other port forwarding tunnel like serveo.net and replace that 10.0.0.2 ip with the given ip and port from these service.

Comment: It's not working with my router ip (4a07:ed0:6dca:7600:898b:c350:efe:73a1)

Comment: thats your ipv6 , not that , go to google and search "what is my ip"and use that ip instead

Comment: 10.0.0.4. what next?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible ***without additional network configuration*** for most home users.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631967/5759254) to a related question will provide you with a detailed explanation of the issues you are facing and how to potentially resolve them.

You will likely need to set up port forwarding on your router.

Comment: it is not useful. they are talking about something different

Comment: No, they aren't. Please re-read it. Do you have port forwarding set up? Are you listening for the connections on the correct IP address? Is your firewall blocking the inbound connection?......All of these things were addressed.

Comment: I do not know how to do all this. Do they explain how to do it?

Comment: Read it and you will find out. Set up static port forwarding in your router's configuration. This is different for each router, so you will have to google the instructions for your specific router.

Answer (score 0):

So far I see 2 possible issues:

1. You are listening for connection only on your local ip address (10.0.0.2)
2. Probably you didn't performed any port forwarding

As regards the first point you can change the local ip with the special *0.0.0.0* to allow connections on every addressable interface. Or you can just set your public ip address (obtainable by [clicking here for IPv4](https://v4.ident.me/) or [here for IPv6](https://v6.ident.me/)).

In short, going for the first option:

```
server.bind(("0.0.0.0", 12345))
```

For the second point it's not too easy to give exact informations since also if going with the simplest solutions it depends on your router. What I can suggest you is trying to go on your router configuration page (that in your case **could be** *10.0.0.1* or *10.0.0.254* and look for *port forwarding* configuration. If you can't find anything I suggest you to google "port forward {yourISPName}". After that you find the forwarding configuration page, you need to forward the port you are using (12345 according to your code) for your device.
In other words you will be asked for:

- A local ip address (the device to which you want to forward the traffic on that specific port): in your case *10.0.0.2* according to your code.
- A port (the port to be forwarded) : *12345* according to your snippet
- A protocol. This is not asked sometimes, but if you are asked for it should be TCP in your case since [it is the default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket) for socket.socket() if not specified otherwise.

You may ask what this port forwarding is. By [quoting wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) for you we have:

> Port forwarding or port mapping is an application of network address
> translation (NAT) that redirects a communication request from one
> address and port number combination to another while the packets are
> traversing a network gateway, such as a router or firewall. This
> technique is most commonly used to make services on a host residing on
> a protected or masqueraded (internal) network available to hosts on
> the opposite side of the gateway (external network), by remapping the
> destination IP address and port number of the communication to an
> internal host.

If you want to go deeper you can refer to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631967/5759254) linked by @kapocsi.

Answer (score 0):

The ip address 10.0.0.2 is an RCF 1918 address. This means it's for "internal" use, and it's not going to be accessible over the public Internet.

So, when the phone is on the same network as the machine running the listening server, the phone can connect to it, because it also has an address in that 10.0.0.x network (likely 10.0.0.0/24). When the phone is using its cellular data connection, it likely has a public (probably IPv6) address. Your phone won't know how to get to 10.0.0.2, and nothing else on the public Internet would, either.

If you have the ability to do port forwarding at your gateway device (your router, or wireless access point, or cable / DSL "model") then you can forward a port on the public IP it has to port 12345 on 10.0.0.2. Then your phone would need to connect to that public IP instead of the private one.

Another alternative would be use a VPN of some sort. So, for example, again, if your gateway device supports it, you can setup a VPN service on it, and then use a corresponding VPN client on the phone to establish a VPN connection. Then the phone should be able to access 10.0.0.2 directly, assuming that your VPN is assigning the appropriate addresses / routing information.

Another option might be use a couple of SSH tunnels to achieve the port forwarding. So, for example, if you have SSH access to a host on the Public Internet, you can setup a reverse SSH tunnel from the machine with your Python server on it:
`ssh -R12345:10.0.0.2:12345 <user>@<public_host>`
Then your phone could connect to port 12345 on <public_host> and it would be forwarded back over the SSH tunnel back to your Python script.

But as it stands right now, the only way to connect the phone to the machine running your code, as you already noted, is to be on the same network (in your base, the wifi).